# Remove list-style from shortcode WordPress Tabbed Menu

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I am having an issue when trying to remove a list-style from a shortcode generated tabbed system within WordPress.  I was successful using the provided solution:

```
.entry-content ul.nav-tabs li { list-style:none; }
```

On the majority of pages the code above works.

Please reference the link below to see how Zoolian's solution worked on this page (you can see listed items below but no list-style on the tabbed menus above):

http://www.drphyllisbooks.com/drbooks2014/books-neural-therapy/what-is-bnt/

Although, there is one page where this is not working.  Please see the following link:

http://www.drphyllisbooks.com/drbooks2014/books-family-health-center/

I would like to remove the bulleted list style from the menu tabbed option and still conserve a list style within the tabbed content area.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.  I received help for this from Zoolian but unfortunately it is not working in this area of the site.

Thank you and I thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: I believe I solved the list-style issue with the following code to the css: ul.nav-tabs li {list-style:none;}  Now, I need to figure out how to make the tabbed menu styled the same throughout all areas.  You can notice that it is bold in the fixed area and not bold on the other area.

Comment: The original solution that Zoolian provided worked with the following code:

    .entry-content ul.nav-tabs li { list-style:none; }

For the other page I added the following two lines of code below:

    ul.nav-tabs li {list-style:none;}
    ul.nav a {font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;line-height:14px;}

I think the page that was causing the problem was nested in another area of an unordered list within WordPress.  I am happy with the result and I just need to fine tune the styles so that that match in both areas.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help you to read something about the specificity of CSS selectors. The specificity decides which CSS attributes get applied to an element. The attributes with the most specific selectors get applied.
In your case `.entry-content ul.nav-tabs li`is more specific than `ul.nav-tabs li` so that's probably the reason why the latter worked for you.

A (very) detailed post about specificity is e.g. this one: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/.

Comment: Thank you wedi I will take a look at the provided link.  Much appreciated!